# Hilbert space on Graph

Tags: graph-theory

Assume we have a finite graph with edges $E$ and nodes $V$. How can one in a sensible way define an inner product on this graph for functions $f:V\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in the nodes  ?  I have seen some different settings: one where we take simply the euclidean inner product - however this does take into account the graph structure, and others which are defined by for example $f' L f$ where $L$ is the graph laplacian. In the latter case we have that the constant functions on fully connected subgraphs are in the null space of $L$ -> so this might not be an inner product will it ?
Do you have any resources I could look at for Hilbert space theory on graphs?

Comment: A bit off but [Graph kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_kernel) might be interesting to you.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_C*-algebra https://www.math.ku.dk/english/research/conferences/2010_and_before/cuntzpimsner/files/tomforde_Talk1.pdf ?

Comment: What problem do you want to solve by taking an inner product on functions $V \to \mathbb R$? There are inner products that make sense to define for some purposes, but we can't say if they're relevant to what you're doing if you don't say what you're doing.

Comment: @Watercrystal  graph kernels are kernels taking as input grpahs. I however look for inner products on a fixed graph instead.

Comment: @MishaLavrov  As I dont know much about inner products I thought there might be an obvious answer as to what a usual inner product is on a graph. Just as we take the l2 space with the integral inner product. Could you elaborate on some inner products which make sense for different purposes ??

Answer (score 2):

The most common inner product to use is just the ordinary Euclidean product; it is used even when it's not the best choice. It's in this setting that you do linear algebra with things like the graph Laplacian, just writing expressions like $\langle f, Lf\rangle$ or possibly normalizing to get $\frac{\langle f, Lf\rangle}{\langle f, f\rangle}$.

This inner product works well when the graph is regular. When the graph is not regular, you see people still using this inner product, and throwing around matrices like the [symmetric normalized Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix#Symmetric_normalized_Laplacian_2) $L^{\text{sym}} = D^{-1/2}L D^{-1/2}$. Instead of doing this,  we could keep our ordinary Laplacian, but change our inner product to something nicer!

An inner product that does this could be written as a weighted average
$$
   \frac1{2|E(G)|} \sum_{v \in V} \deg(v) f(v) g(v)
$$
but that doesn't explain why it's nice. To do that, consider a random walk on $G$. The stationary distribution $\pi$ of the random walk visits vertex $v$ with probability $\pi(v) = \frac{\deg(v)}{2|E(G)|}$. Then, define the inner product $\langle f,g\rangle_{\pi}$ as the expected value $$\langle f,g\rangle_\pi = \mathbb E_{\boldsymbol v \sim \pi} [f(\boldsymbol v) g(\boldsymbol v)]
$$
where by $\boldsymbol v \sim \pi$ I mean that $\boldsymbol v$ is a random vertex sampled from the stationary distribution $\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for you answer ! Do you have any resources? So usually one uses the  regular inner product with the graph laplacian matrix in some way on a graph ? If I do so then constant functions are discared right ? as under this IP they have norm zero. Is this a sensible assumption to make ?

Comment: No, our inner product has nothing to do with the Laplacian matrix. We consider the ordinary Euclidean product, and one of the things we do with it is investigate the quadratic form $\langle f, Lf\rangle$.

Comment: What I know about spectral graph theory is what I learned from [this class](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~odonnell/toolkit13/). If you want a starting point, you can read the three lectures on spectral graph theory there.